# case of different column names and dynamic number of columns in asp.net grid view according to the sql procedure result

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a stored procedure with dynamic sql query, the result of query has 3 cases:

1. for one condition it outputs 3 columns `[ID, CODE_DESC, REMARKS]`
2. second condtion it outputs 5 columns `[ID, CODE_DESC, PRESSURE, CHOLESTROL, FASTING_SUGAR]`
3. third condtion it outputs 5 columns but the output column names are different for 2 and 3 condition `[ID, CODE_DESC, RENAL_TEST, LIVER_TEST, BLOOD_SERUM]`

Now I have to create a grid view to display data. One way is to create 3 different grid view and make visible only that grid view which 
satisfies the given condition.

But is there any other way of doing it ?

How can I create a dynamic grid view according to the number of columns and also according to the names of the columns of a DataTable ?

Comment: Is the grid read-only or do you need CRUD capabilities?

Comment: read only, just fetch data and show. thank you